# How to get results based on current context language using rendering variant Search Build Query?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-query, sxa-search

I am using rendering variant query item to write the search build query to get the related items.

I want to query items that should also match current user context language.

I have tried using `language: en` explicitly in the query to check but still I get items in the result other than English:

[image]

Please find the attached query:

```
+template:{342696b0-2b67-406f-c7acc7894741};+sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;+language:en;+sort:__smallupdateddate_tdt[desc]
```

[image]

Comment: To get the English language result in build query, you need to use `language:english`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `language` field in the Search Query Builder is mapped to the index field `parsedlanguage`. It means that this field is looking at the full language names, for example *"english"*, *"english_united_states"*, *german_germany"* instead of culture codes like *"en"*, *"en-US"*, *"de-DE"*.

So if you want to search by the context language **code**, consider using the `culture` field in your search query like this:

```
custom:culture|en
```

[image: Search query with culture field]

You can also try using the `language` field, but be careful if you have more than one culture for the same language on the website because the following query will return results for all matching languages ("English", "English (United States)", etc.):

```
language:english
```

[image: Search query with language field]